# Rails mass assignment definition and attr_accessible use

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mass-assignment

Just want to be clear on what mass assignment is and how to code around it. Is **mass assignment** the assignment of many fields using a hash, ie like..

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
```

And to prevent this you use **attr_accessible** like:

```
attr_accessible :name, :email
```

So that a field like :admin could not be added by mass assignment?

But we can modify it in code by something like:

```
@user.admin = true
```

So is it true that if we don't have **attr_accessible** then everything is accessible for mass assignment?

And finally the tricky point ... is it true that even with one **attr_accessible** like "attr_accessible :name" means that **all** other fields are now **not** accessible for mass assignment?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All of your assumptions are correct. Without attr_accessible, all fields are open to mass assignment. If you start using attr_accessible, only the fields you specify are open to mass assignment.

Answer (score 6):

As pointed out by Srdjan all of your assumptions are correct. Just so you know, there is also an attr_protected method which is the opposite of attr_accessible.

In other words

```
attr_protected :admin
```

will prevent :admin from being mass-assigned but will allow all other fields.

Answer (score 3):

Srdjan's answer is correct assuming that `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes` is set to `false` in your `config/application.rb`.

If it is set to `true`, all attributes will be **protected from mass assignment by default** unless `attr_accessible` or `attr_protected` is used.