# can't mass-assign protected attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

need some help with some associations in my rails app. Get a "can't mass-assign protected attributes: rss_readers" warning and don't figured out what's the problem.

```
class Scraper < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :link, :rss_reader_attributes

  has_one :rss_reader
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rss_reader
```

And the accociation:

```
class RssReader < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :address, :content 

  belongs_to :scraper
```

At the rails console its works fine.

```
> scraper = Scraper.new 
> scraper.build_rss_reader 
> scraper.attributes={:rss_reader_attributes=>{:address => "asdsad"}}
```

But in controller i get the warning.

```
  def new
    @scraper = Scraper.new
    @scraper.build_rss_reader
  end

  def create
    @scraper = Scraper.new(params[:scraper])
    @scraper.build_rss_reader

    if @scraper.save
      redirect_to :show
    else
      render :new
    end
```

And thats the new view

```
<%= form_for(@scraper) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <%= f.fields_for(@scraper.rss_reader) do |rss| %>
     <div class="field">
         <%= rss.label :address %><br />
         <%= rss.text_field :address %>
     </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I thougth that's all right but i get the warning. Anyone have an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=38445) you may need to explicitly add `RssReader` to `:attr_accessible`.

Comment: this didn't work. i add :rss_reader to :attr_accessible. get this error. RssReader(#70085183525060) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#9179800)

Answer (score 2):

Basically when you say something to be attribute accessible, then you cannot mass assign that particular attribute ... so the error you are getting is right.
You cannot do object.update_attributes

```
what you can try is do 
@rssreader = rssreader.new
@rssreader.address = 'the address'
and then 
@scrapper.rssreader = @rssreader
```

Refer this for a better idea on attr_accessible 
[Rails mass assignment definition and attr_accessible use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277191/rails-mass-assignment-definition-and-attr-accessible-use)

Comment: thanks for response. so I thought I would have understood the mass assignment technique, so thats why I added rss_reader_attributes to the parent model. because I would like to create a scraper object and a child, nested object RSS reader in a form. i think there must be a way to create a scraper with rss_reader accociation and write the nested attributes. by the way my english is not so good, I hope I express myself to understand.

Comment: yeah get it. my mistake wasn't in the controller or the model. I've to used the :rss_reader symbol instead of  @scraper.rss_reader in the field field_for at my new view. but i don't understood exactly why or where is it create?