# collection_select not saving selected option in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have `collection_select` in one of my views, which properly creates a HTML `<select>` menu, but when I select an option it does not save in the database. In the same view I have other fields from the same db table and they save up. Here are my models:

```
class TrainingPart < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :activity
  belongs_to :training  
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :activity, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :training_parts 
end
```

The partial is:

```
<div class="part">
  <%= f.label :activity, "Activity" %>
  <%= collection_select :training_part, :activity_id, Activity.all, :id, :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :activity_id %>
  <%= f.text_field :amount %>  
</div>
```

The `amount` field works fine.

**EDIT:** I don't use `attr_accessible` in any model, so all of the fields in all tables are accessible. (reference: [Rails mass assignment definition and attr_accessible use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277191/rails-mass-assignment-definition-and-attr-accessible-use))

Comment: Do you have `attr_accessible :activity_id` in your `TrainingPart` model?

Comment: no, and when I added it there was the following error: `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: amount`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it. It turned out that I had 2 mistakes:

1) I had to remove `<%= f.text_field :activity_id %>` from the view as this was the field, which I was trying to set with the select menu.

2) I should've used `f.collection_select` instead of `collection_select`

Answer (score 0):

Allow mass-assignment to whatever attributes you want settable from the view:

```
attr_accessible :activity_id, :amount # ...any others...
```

"Mass-assignment" means setting many attributes at once with data from the view, such as from forms. These attributes are protected by default to prevent users from injecting their own values (eg. `admin = true`).

Use `attr_accessible` to declare which of your model's attributes are mass-assignable.

Also, since you are accepting nested attributes for `Activity`, you must include `:activity_attributes` among your list of accessible attributes.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I didn't whitelist the field in my controller.

Say your select menu has blog posts as options so you can choose what blog a comment belongs to

```
f.collection_select :post_id, Post.all, :id, :name
```

Then you'll need to permit `post_id` in your `CommentsController`

```
def update
  # ...
  if @comment.update_attributes(post_params)
  # ...
end

def post_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:name, :post_id)  # Make sure the field used with your select menu is permitted! 
end
```